# How Do I fix this Magebuzz Testimonial Extension?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, extensions

Recently, I purchased and installed a Testimonial extension for Magento2 from Magebuzz.

http://www.magebuzz.com/free-testimonial-for-magento-2.html

The customer service has been non-existent. So, I would like to try to fix this myself, but I'm not sure the exact problem. I'm wondering if anyone with great troubleshooting skills can help or has dealt with extension will know. Here's what happened.

I uploaded all of the Magebuzz Testimonial files to my root magento2. 
Then I ran the command lines:

```
php /bin/magento module:enable Magebuzz_Core
php /bin/magento module:enable Magebuzz_Testimonial
php /bin/magento setup:upgrade
php /bin/magento setup:di:compile
php /bin/magento cache:flush
```

So when I log into my admin panel and refresh magento cache, also flush magento cache and magento cache storage. I do successfully see that the Testimonial extension and its components (configuration inputs, etc) has been added to the Admin panel. However when I click on the Content section --> Testimonial --> Memo to create a manual testimonial, no matter what when I click the OK button to finally save and enter the manual testimonial, the page just turns white and does nothing else. Not eve spin the wheel in the browser tab to show that it's doing anything. It does nothing. This leads me to believe that something was missing from the extension files. I looked in the Database for any tables named Magebuzz or Testimonial - there were NONE. I would think there should be a DB table to at least hold all of the entries, right? Also the link in the browser of the white static page after attempting to add the manual testimonial was something like this:

https://www.myWebsite.com/myAdmin/testimonial/memo/save/key/40bd44249b899735620494b253c683b976e412b2171aAAf40368177244f4b025/active_tab/main_section/

I am using Magento 2.1.7, on linux, PHP 7

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you check the log files under var/logs

Comment: OK. My error log is where the issue showed up. It says: [25-Oct-2017 06:13:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Redefinition of parameter $filesystem in /home/DOC/ROOTDOC/app/code/Magebuzz/Testimonial/Controller/Adminhtml/Memo/Save.php on line 48

Answer (score 2):

Same error for me, it seems that the $filesystem  member of the class is declared twice.
So you should remove the second one in app/code/Magebuzz/Testimonial/Controller/A‌​dminhtml/Memo/Save.p‌​hp line 57

```
    public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js $jsHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploader,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,

    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
)
```